How to resolve (SDK issues) Google Play Core (com.google.android.play:core)?
I have extended deadline for publishing sdk 34+, now I need to publish hot fixes on current version 33 and it throws errors. I cannot now update the versions because need to change whole project. Why it gives error when publishing on production but when trying to publish to internal test it shows only warning. enter image description here

Error
Google Play Core (com.google.android.play:core) has added this note to SDK version 1.9.1:
Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration
You must update to a newer version to release future versions of your app to production or open testing.
Learn more about the SDKs that you're using and make informed SDK choices with Google Play SDK Index.

I tried to remove the libs com.google.android.play:core but it still says that it is in the project

Update all your dependencies to their latest versions. Use the Gradle dependency report to see which ones are using com.google.android.play:core.
